# Trying to bind in class on a click event but gets an error of "Property "XXX" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance. "

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3

Hello everyone I'm trying to bind a click event on a button to toggle a class on vue but I'm kinda stuck on the following code, can you help me with some tips and examples

my structure

```
dashboard.vue
|_Sidebar.vue  Sidebar Component 
|_Mainpage     
|_SidebarJs // this is where all my function should be called by sidebar component
```

**My Dashboard code**

```
<template>
<Head title="Dashboard" />
<SideBar />
  <!-- start: Main -->
  <main class="w-full md:w-[calc(100%-256px)] md:ml-64 bg-gray-50 min-h-screen transition-all main">
    <div class="py-2 px-6 bg-white flex items-center shadow-md shadow-black/5 sticky top-0 left-0 z-30">
        <button type="button" class="text-lg text-gray-600 sidebar-toggle" @click="SidebarJs.ToggleMenu">
            <i class="ri-menu-line" ></i>
        </button>
    </div>

    <!-- Some very long line of codes for other sections of dashboard  -->
  </main>
```

**Sidebar.vue code**

```
<template>
<div
    :class="[`${isexpanded?'active':''}`]"
    class="fixed left-0 top-0 w-64 h-full bg-gray-900 p-4 z-50 sidebar-menu transition-transform">   
</div>
 <!-- Some very long line of codes for other sections of Sidebar  -->
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
   const isexpanded = ref(false)
    var FunctionScripts = {
    ToggleMenu () {
            isexpanded.value = !isexpanded.value
            console.log('test')       
    },
    foo () {
        const activeClass = ref('active')
        const errorClass = ref('text-danger')
        console.log('foo')
    },
    bar () { console.log('bar') }
  }
  export default FunctionScripts
```

**import scripts**

```
import { Head } from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import SideBar from '../Components/Sidebar.vue';
import SidebarJs from '@/../../resources/js/Functions/Sidebar';
import {ref} from 'vue';
```

**my references for the codes i learn are from youtube and docs**
https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/class-and-style.html#class-and-style-bindings

**my older code works only if all of the codes are not split up or inside a single vue but i want it to be organize so thats why i cant use these codes anymore**

**old code**

```
<script setup>
import {ref} from 'vue';
const isexpanded = ref(false)
const ToggleMenu = ()=> {
    isexpanded.value = !isexpanded.value
}
</script>
```

Comment: did you import `ref` in your sidebar.js?

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth oh do i have to declare it again even though i declared it out side sorry i'll try it right away

Comment: it works but gave me a new error Property "isexpanded" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance.

Comment: When you need to pass values to child components, you need to use props inside the child. The code inside each component is scoped to that file (except style, unless scoped)

Comment: not sure about your particular code. but if Sidebar.vue needs to use Sidebar.js to function, then you need to import Sidebar.js inside Sidebar.vue. something like `import FunctionScripts from Sidebar.js` then use FunctionScripts to return the ref value.

Comment: @Second2None thanks for the tip..I solve the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the answer for myself with the help from the comments by adding props to access the child component to parent

**Dashboard.vue**

```
const isexpanded = ref(false)
const ToggleMenu = ()=> {
SidebarJs.ToggleMenu(isexpanded)
console.log(isexpanded.value)
return isexpanded
}

<template> 
  <SideBar :isexpanded="isexpanded"/>
</template>
```

**Sidebar.js**

```
defineProps({
  title: String,
  isexpanded: String
})
```

**SidebarJs**

```
var FunctionScripts = {

    ToggleMenu (isexpanded) {

        //console.log(data)
        isexpanded.value = !isexpanded.value

        return isexpanded

    },
    foo (data) {


        return data
    },
    bar () { console.log('bar') }
  }
  export default FunctionScripts
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should export and import `isexpanded` too from your `Sidebar.js` file